# .htaccess equivalent in .NetCore

Tags: .htaccess, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

To allow video to be played in  element from my website, but not allowing it through direct link, I created .htaccess in a sub-directory with the source videos, and nothing else. with the below code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(mp4|mp3|avi)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://sample.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

I need to do the same with .NetCore server, but do not know how?

Any help. thanks.

Comment: If you means MVC, you can do routing easily. if you means webforms the check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx

Comment: .NET Core does not support WebForms, but routing is definitely there. Is that the only approach? Well, I guess that if I don't want to hardcore rewrite URLs in the code, I can have the routing class read a configuration file.

Comment: ah this looks like what we need here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple approach to this problem would be an application level solution using .NET Core by simply denying requests based on referrer in your controller by [checking referrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772394/how-can-i-get-url-referrer-in-asp-net-core-mvc) header.

If you run .NET Core application(s) using IIS, then you could use IIS rewrite rules specifying them in `web.config`, and this approach would look similar to `.htaccess` one. [Several examples](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292141/IIS-Rewrite-rules-that-you-can-t-live-without).

The application level solution might be a little bit slower, however has better visibility to developers and is easier to maintain.